# the email for new order notification doesn't sent

Tags: magento-1.9, email, order-email, notification

I have problem with the email notification it doesn't send to customer
I have searched for it and found that it needs to set up the Cron job. I did setup it but still, nothing sent.

this is the Cron job
http://prntscr.com/htuohp

I hope you can help me with that.
thank you
Magento 1.9

Comment: Please use AOE scheduler free extension so you can easily check the cron is running or not. Also check the cron table in database

Answer (score 1):

Executing the cron via `wget` seems a little odd to me.
In case your shop is running on an apache webserver please see the .htaccess file starting at around line ~228. There is a `Deny from all` condition for cron.php which will prevent you from executing cron.php in this way.
You may set up your cron like

```
php /path/to/magento-root/cron.php
```